# Is it OK to Add Digit Buttons above the keyboard in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, input, keyboard, coding-style

I am writing an iPhone application.  In one of my views the user will have to enter Canadian zip codes which alternate letters and numbers (e.g. V0E 5N0). I would like to have the default keyboard showing up, but additionally, I want to allow the user to be able to enter numbers without having to switch keyboards back and forth by pressing the ".?123" key, which makes the process tedious for this type of entry.   Will my app violate apple guidelines if I add into my view 10 buttons with the digits to show right above the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of Apps that already exist on the App store with such functionality, so I don't see why your App would get rejected specifically for having a view above the keyboard.  It may still get declined because of other things, but not a custom keyboard view.

[Nebulous Notes - Approved and on the App store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/nebulous-notes-for-dropbox/id375006422?ign-mpt=uo%3D5):

[image: Nebulous Notes]

[iSSH](http://itunes.apple.com/app/issh-ssh-vnc-console/id287765826?mt=8) also has a custom keyboard with toolbar on iphone and ipad and is on the App store.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the information I needed.  I tried to vote your response up, but I don't have the necessary points so it does not let me vote.

Comment: @glsaza Happy to help.  You can click the checkmark below the down arrow to accept this answer if you feel it is an acceptable answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally incase of a zip code entry , users are provided with a `UINumberKeyPad` and it makes it easy for them (But in your case it would not help you). In your case, if you wish to add another `UIToolbar` right on top of the `inputView`, I would say go for it, but it is not the best practice !

This **will not** violate the apple guidelines, and you can implement in your view with a `UIToolbar` as an `inputAccessoryView`. Make sure to remove the `Toolbar` from the `superView` during the keyboard event `resignFirstResponder`.

Comment: UINumberKeyPad doesn't have any letters

Comment: Yes @Jonathan.  I am aware of that.

Comment: and as the OP says Canadian zip codes have both letters and numbers in them.

Comment: Yes @Jonathan. That is why I had suggested an `inputAccessoryView`.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try to using inputAccessoryView as you suggest.  I tried to vote you up for your answer, but my "reputation" does not allow me to vote. :(  I'm new posting in stack overflow.